# Sending recieved messages from Twilio to Firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, twilio

I just want to ask if it is possible to have Twilio receive messages from the user and upload their message to Firebase realtime database? I found a project that uses Twilio and Firebase cloud function but is there any Twilio and firebase realtime database integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible with [Zapier](https://zapier.com/). However it isn't cost-effective for my project so that has to go and I am just currently going for making a cheap SMS gateway using a USB SMS modem.